# make version dependency for using test

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to use `test` in a `make` target, specifically to check for changes to certain files with `git` (I don't think that particular `git diff-index HEAD --` command makes a difference here).

```
is_diff:
    if [[ -n `git diff-index HEAD --` ]]; exit 1; fi
```

This works fine as a bash script, but as a `make` target it seems to be dependent on which version of `make` is running, which limits its utility (and makes just pointing to a shell script version better).

Is there a change that would *make* this a little more `make`-version independent?

Comment: Use `[ -n "\`git diff-index HEAD --\`" ]` instead of the bash-specific `[[ -n ... ]]`?

Comment: Also you're missing the `then` keyword before `exit 1`.

Answer (score 0):

> Use `` [ -n "`git diff-index HEAD --`" ] `` instead of the bash-specific [[ -n ... ]]

was the correct answer from a comment by Renaud Pacalet.

Also as MadScientist notes, that the original question omitted `then` so

`` if [ -n "`git diff-index HEAD --`" ]; then exit 1; fi ``